# Node.js - how to calculate the aggregate(sum) of sub document in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

My collection structure was,

```
[{
    "_id": "....",
    "name": "aaaa",
    "level_max_leaves": [{
        level: "ObjectIdString 1",
        max_leaves: 4,
    }]
}, {
    "_id": "....",
    "name": "bbbb",
    "level_max_leaves": [{
        level: "ObjectIdString 1",
        max_leaves: 4,
    }]
}, {
    "_id": "....",
    "name": "cccc",
    "level_max_leaves": [{
        level: "ObjectIdString 1",
        max_leaves: 7,
    }]
}, {
    "_id": "....",
    "name": "dddd",
    "level_max_leaves": [{
        level: "ObjectIdString 2",
        max_leaves: 3,
    }]
}]
```

Now I need to sum the field of `max_leaves` which has the `ObjectIdString 1`?

And the result of `(4+4+7=15)`.

so far I tried

```
var empLevelId = 1234... ;
MyModel.aggregate(
    {$unwind: "$level_max_leaves.level"},
    {$match: {"$level_max_leaves.level": empLevelId } },
    {$group: { "_id": "$level_max_leaves.level", 
               "total": { "$sum": "$level_max_leaves.max_leaves" }}},
    function (err, res) {
        console.log(res);
});
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: $max_leaves is most likely no field in the object, try $level_max_leaves.max_leaves

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally when dealing with arrays in the aggregation framework you need to [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the array contents first. This "de-normalizes" the content as individual documents. From here normal grouping operations work as expected:

```
MyModel.aggregate([

    // Unwind to "de-normalize"
    { "$unwind": "$level_max_leaves" },

    // Group as expected
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$level_max_leaves.level",
        "total": { "$sum": "$level_max_leaves.max_leaves" }
    }}

],function(err,result) {

    // process results here

});
```

Note also that the "absolute" paths are required when addressing elements.

Comment: Yeah. Now I have one more doubt. How can I calculate total of `max_leaves` based on `level` object string as `ObjectIdString 1` or `ObjectIdString 2` or `ObjectIdString 3`?

Comment: @Ranjith Not sure what you are asking. That is what the above does. Returns the total of "max_leaves" per each value of "level". If you have another question then feel free to post another question. This answers the question you asked. You can explain what you want more clearly with another question.

Comment: Yeah. Now I need to filter the particular `level` of total `max_leaves`. I tried with `$match` filter option like, `$match: {"$level_max_leaves.level": empLevelId } }` . But its not returned what I expected. I edited my question too.

Comment: @Ranjith Again this sounds like another question. I have answered the question you asked. Post another question if there is something else you need explaining. It's clearer to people that way.